# ASP.NET events symbol (yellow lightning bolt) missing

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

I created a new C# ASP.NET Web Application project in .NET 3.5
Then I dragged a button in my form.

In the property window the events symbol (yellow lightning bolt) does not show. When I double click the box next to 'OnClientClick' in the properties Window no default event handler is created. When I double click the button in design view no event handler is created either.

Any ideas on how I can get the events symbol and the automatic generation of a default event handler?

Comment: I would suggest you to check generated markup for button. You might also want to check AutoEventWireup attribute of Page Directive, which will wire up default event for the given control. More info can be found out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you didn't have the option checked for "Place code in a separate file" when adding the webform?  Also "OnClientClick" isn't a server side event, it is just a string property so it wouldn't ever map to a server side event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the tag that is being used for your control. If it looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" runat="server" value="OK" id="btn_1" />
```

then there will never be an Events symbol. Adding runat="server" to a regular HTML tag turns it into a rather basic Server'ified HTML control, with properties *and* events, yet Visual Studio does not recognize it as a control with events. (So events do exist, but you'll have to write all the necessary code and declarations yourself)

If the above is the case, rewrite it to this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="OK" id="btn_2" />
```

and then the Events symbol will be there. `<asp:Button>` creates a full featured Server Side Web Control, which in the end *renders* similar output, while offering a much richer set of features (such as Design mode support).